# Using Google AppEngine app as a OAuth provider

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using the Google AppEngine 1.3.4 SDK which offers to allow your application to act as a OAuth service provider (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/). Setting up a standard application on my localhost and using the following:

```
Request URL /_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken
Authorize URL /_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken
Access Token URL /_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken
```

The client application just gets sent to a page requesting to grant OAuth access even though no user is logged in. Clicking 'Grant access' results in a message saying 'OAuth access granted' with no tokens or anything exchange. Can't see how this could work when it's not even prompting for a login.

As this functionality is quite new I can't find much out there. I've created a OAuth provider before in Rails and know that you need a Consumer Key and Secret, something that seems to be lacking in GAE?

Any ideas on how to get OAuth working in a sample GAE project are most welcome.

Comment: Did you get it working? Can you share you code for client? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to dig this up, but I"m having the same problem. The funny thing is that this was working perfectly fine a few weeks ago, but now it is now. The only difference is that I was using AppEngine 1.6.x a couple weeks ago, and am not using 1.7.0.

Comment: I'm no longer using GAE but never did manage to get that to work. Perhaps someone else might have a suggestion or two... Good luck and if you do find something I'd be interested to know what the solution was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that the SDK implementation simply grants access regardless. It's also possible you still have a dev_appserver login cookie. Either way, try it in production - it'll almost certainly request login in that case.

Comment: Yeah you're indeed correct, when deployed to production authorisation occurs as you'd except it with Google prompting for a login. Obviously it does make it somewhat difficult to test things locally at times!